# Path name in shell script contains extra characters when script is run

Tags: shell-script, shell, path, mtp

I am working on a script that partially automates backing up contents of an MTP device. Before continuing, I am trying to verify that the relevant folders can be accessed, by adding a line that opens a folder in nemo. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "mtp://[usb:[BUS],[DEVICE]]"
echo -n "Enter BUS: "
read BUS
echo -n "Enter DEVICE: "
read DEVICE
nemo /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A$BUS%2C$DEVICE%5D/Internal%20shared%20storage/
```

The first "echo"-line is just for user reference.

$BUS and $DEVICE are correctly substituted with the entered values, resulting in the correct path for the root of the MTP device, but the following folder isn't interpreted correctly, as I get the following error message:

```
"Could not find "mtp://[usb:002,036]/Internal%2520shared%2520storage".

Please check the spelling and try again.

[OK]"
```

Where does the twice added "25" come from and how can I remedy this so the script opens the correct path in nemo?

Comment: isn't **25** hexadecimal ascii code for `%` ? I expect `%20` turn to `%2520`

Comment: try quoting and use space.

Comment: @Archemar Where should I place the quotes and the space? I am an absolute beginner when it comes to shell scripting.

Comment: I agree, quote the path string.

Comment: nemo "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A$BUS%2C$DEVICE%5D/Internal shared storage/"

Comment: @Archemar Edited comment, got ninja'd. Your suggestion works. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helps, I dodn't know about this protocol though.

Answer (score 1):

Archemar's suggestion of substituting %20 with a space and using double quote around the path string remedied my problem and results in the folder being opened correctly.